# How to Enable C++11 Features in Codelite

Tags: c++, c++11, codelite, enum-class

The following code compiles and runs in Xcode 5 and in Visual Studio 2013.  I am interested in trying out Codelite, but Codelite will not compile the following program (a problem since I am working with scoped enums in my project).  As far as I understand it, Codelite is using the same compiler as Xcode.

Is the code valid per C++11?  Why is Codelite unable to compile it?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace abc
{
    namespace xyz
    {
        enum class SampleEnum
        {
            SomeValue = 0,
            SomeOtherValue = 1
        };
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    abc::xyz::SampleEnum e = abc::xyz::SampleEnum::SomeValue;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the build output from Codelite.  In case it's garbled, it's pointing to the word "SampleEnum" in the instantiation of the variable and saying "expected a class or namespace".

```
/bin/sh -c 'make -j8 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ ClangTest - Debug ]----------
codelite-cc /usr/bin/clang++   -c  "/Users/xxx/Desktop/Test/ClangTest/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Test/ClangTest/main.cpp:7:8: warning: scoped enumerations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
                enum class SampleEnum
                     ^
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Test/ClangTest/main.cpp:17:40: error: expected a class or namespace
    abc::xyz::SampleEnum e = abc::xyz::SampleEnum::SomeValue;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [Debug/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make: *** [All] Error 2
2 errors, 1 warnings
```

Comment: Seems Codelite does not like C++11: 'warning: scoped enumerations are a C++11 extension '

Comment: It looks like your compiler is not running in C++11 mode, try adding the switch `-std=c++11`

Comment: I think you should put your Edit as an answer to your own question. Indeed it may help someone in the future, but may skip reading it thinking it is a continuation of your question instead.

Comment: @CygnusX1 I have followed your suggestion and moved my Codelite instructions to an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is necessary to pass -std=c++11 to the compiler to enable C++11 features.  Here are the steps to do so in Codelite:

- Right click on the project in the workspace view.
- Select Settings near the bottom of this pop-up menu. Common Settings->Compiler->C++ Compiler Options
- Click into the semicolon delimited list of compiler switches to reveal elipses and click on the elipses.
- Click the checkbox for -std=c++11

[image: screenshot of the project settings windows]

Comment: Just a comment: CodeLite does not "compile" codelite is an IDE, which invokes the compiler (in your case, gcc). So the title is a bit misleading.

Comment: This is a perfect/standard way in CodeLite to invoke compiler's support for C++11. BTW: a lot of compiler's options can be selected here as you can see.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using C++11 extensions, compilers want it to be flagged. Without it they may throw warnings and errors. That's because some of C++11 changes are not backward-compatible, e.g. the use of `auto`.

For example, in gcc you should have

```
gcc -std=c++11
```

Check if your compiler shouldn't have such parameter as well!

Comment: `--std=c++11` is also valid

Comment: BTW, you might upgrade your GCC compiler. Recent version is 4.9

Comment: Good point, @BasileStarynkevitch. GCC 4.9 also supports C++14, which is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is because that your default std version is not c++11. To change to c++11, if you are using your terminal, you should type in the following command:

```
g++ yourfile.cpp -std=c++11
```