# C++ Compiler Error: How to enable -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, codelite

I writing a program a program for Exam Report in C++. I don't see any error in my code but I each time I execute the code, it gives me the following error:

```
#ifndef _CXX0X_WARNING_H
#define _CXX0X_WARNING_H 1

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#endif

#endif
```

I am using 3 files in this program..one header file and 2 cpp source file.

Following is my header file ExamReport.h

```
#ifndef EXAMREPORT_H_
#define EXAMREPORT_H_

#include <string>
#include <array>

class ExamReport {

public:
    static const size_t studentNum = 10;

    ExamReport(const std::string &, const std::array<int, studentNum> &);

    void setModuleName(const std::string &);
    std::string getModuleName() const;
    void displayMessage() const;
    void processMarks() const;
    int getMinimum() const;
    int getMaximum() const;
    double getAverage() const;
    void outputBarChart() const;
    void outputMarks() const;

    private:
    std::string moduleName; // module name
    std::array<int, studentNum> marks; // array of student marks
};

#endif
```

This is my ExamReport.cpp (class manipulation) File.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "ExamReport.h"
using namespace std;

ExamReport::ExamReport(const string &name, const array<int, studentNum> &marksArray) :

moduleName(name), marks(marksArray) {
}

void ExamReport::setModuleName(const string &name) {
moduleName= name; // store the module name
}

string ExamReport::getModuleName() const {
return moduleName;
}

void ExamReport::displayMessage() const {
cout << "Exam Report for\n"<< getModuleName() << "!"<< endl;
}

void ExamReport::processMarks() const {
/* output marks array*/
outputMarks();

/* call function getAverageto calculate the average mark */
cout<< setprecision(2) << fixed;

cout<< "\nClassaverage is "<< getAverage() << endl;

/* call functions getMinimumand getMaximum*/
cout<< "Lowest mark is "<< getMinimum() << "\nHighestmark is "
<< getMaximum() << endl;

/* call function outputBarChartto print mark distribution chart*/
outputBarChart();
}

int ExamReport::getMinimum() const {

    int lowMark= 100; // assume lowest mark is 100

/* loop through marks array */

for(int mark : marks) {

// if current mark lower than lowMark, assign it to lowMark
if (mark < lowMark)
      lowMark = mark; // new lowest mark
}

return lowMark; // return lowest mark
}

int ExamReport::getMaximum() const {

int highMark= 0;   // assume highest mark is 0

// loop through marks array
for (int mark : marks) {
// if current mark higher than highMark, assign it to highMark

if (mark > highMark)
    highMark= mark; // new highest mark
}

return highMark; // return highest mark
}

double ExamReport::getAverage() const {
int total = 0; // initialize total

// sum marks in array
for (int mark : marks )
total += mark;

// return average of marks
return static_cast<double>(total) / marks.size();
}


void ExamReport::outputBarChart() const {
cout<< "\nMarkdistribution:"<< endl;

/* stores frequency of marks in each range of 10 marks*/
const size_t frequencySize= 11;
array<unsigned int, frequencySize > frequency = { }; // init to 0s

/* for each mark, increment the appropriate frequency*/
for(int mark : marks)
++frequency[mark / 10];

/* for each mark frequency, print bar in chart*/
for(size_t count = 0; count < frequencySize; ++count) {
/* output bar labels ("0-9:", ..., "90-99:", "100:" )*/

if (0 == count)
cout << " 0-9: ";
else if (10 == count)
cout<< " 100: ";
else
cout<< count * 10 << "-"<< (count * 10) + 9 << ": ";

/* print bar of asterisks*/
for (unsigned int stars = 0; stars < frequency[count]; ++stars)
cout<< '*';
cout<< endl; // start a new line of output
}
}

void ExamReport::outputMarks() const {
cout<< "\nThemarks are:\n\n";

/* output each student's mark*/
for(size_t student = 0; student < marks.size(); ++student)
cout<< "Student "<< setw(2) << student + 1 << ": "<< setw(3)<<
marks[student] << endl;
}
```

This is my 3rd file which includes the main function TestMain.cpp

```
#include <array>
#include "ExamReport.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
// array of student marks

const array<int, ExamReport::studentNum> marks = { 85,63,92,100,73,78,85,66,76,45};
string moduleName= "ECS769P Advanced Object-Oriented Programming";
ExamReport myExamReport(moduleName, marks);
myExamReport.displayMessage();
myExamReport.processMarks();
}
```

NOTE: I am using CodeLite IDE (version 9.0.7) for this program

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172050/how-to-migrate-to-c-11-in-an-opensource-ide-codelite).

Comment: This link was extremely help full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28779334/how-to-enable-c11-features-in-codelite